# JavaScript asynchronous programming: promises vs generators

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, ecmascript-6

Promises and generators allow you to write asynchronous code. I do not understand why both of these mechanisms are introduced in ECMA script 6. When is it best to use the promises, and when the generators?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

There is no opposition between these two techniques: they coexist together complementing each other nicely.

*Promises* allows you to get the result of an asynchronous operation which is not available *yet*.
It solves the [Pyramid of Doom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_of_doom_(programming)) problem. So instead of:

```js
function ourImportantFunction(callback) {
  //... some code 1
  task1(function(val1) {
    //... some code 2
    task2(val1, function(val2) {
      //... some code 3
      task3(val2, callback);
    });
  });
}
```

you can write:

```js
function ourImportantFunction() {
  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(function() {
        //... some code 1
        return task1(val3)
    })
    .then(function(val2) {
        //... some code 2
        return task2(val2)
    })
    .then(function(val2) {
        //... some code 3
        return task3(val2);
    });
}

ourImportantFunction().then(callback);
```

But even with promises you must write code in asynchronous fashion - you must always pass callbacks to the functions.
Writing asynchronous code is much harder than synchronous. Even with promises, when the code is huge, it becomes difficult to see the algorithm (it's very subjective, but for the majority of programmers I think it's true).

So we want to write asynchronous code in synchronous fashion. That's where *generators* are coming to help us.
Instead of the code above you can write:

```
var ourImportantFunction = spawn(function*() {
    //... some code 1
    var val1 = yield task1();
    //... some code 2
    var val2 = yield task2(val1);
    //... some code 3
    var val3 = yield task3(val2);

    return val3;
});

ourImportantFunction().then(callback);
```

where the simplest possible `spawn` realization can be something like:

```
function spawn(generator) {
  return function() {    
    var iter = generator.apply(this, arguments);

    return Promise.resolve().then(function onValue(lastValue){
      var result = iter.next(lastValue); 

      var done  = result.done;
      var value = result.value;

      if (done) return value; // generator done, resolve promise
      return Promise.resolve(value).then(onValue, iter.throw.bind(iter)); // repeat
    });
  };
}
```

As you can see `value` (result of some asynchronous function `task{N}`) must be a promise. You can't do this with callbacks.

What remains to do is to implement the `spawn` technique into the language itself. So we are replacing `spawn` with `async` and `yield` with `await` and are coming to [ES7 async/await](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:async_functions):

```
var ourImportantFunction = async function() {
    //... some code 1
    var val1 = await task1();
    //... some code 2
    var val2 = await task2(val1);
    //... some code 3
    var val3 = await task3(val2);

    return val3;
}
```

I recommend you to watch [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DqMFX91ToLw) to understand more this and some other coming techniques.
*Hint:* If the guy speaks too fast for you, slow down the speed of playing ("settings" in right bottom corner, or just push [<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd>])

**What is the best:** only callbacks, or promises, or promises with generators - this is a very subjective question.
Callbacks is the fastest solution possible at this time (performance of native promises are very bad now). Promises with generators give you opportunity to write asynchronous code in synchronous fashion. But for now they are much slower than simple callbacks.

Comment: Also, can I refactor the deferred anti pattern out of it while I'm at it? Good answer by the way. (Promises are not really slow, a closure + callback is slower than a bluebird promise most of the time)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum `bluebird` is really blazing fast. But we are talking about ES6 now.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Hmm... `arguments` bug was already fixed in all browsers?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum By the way - yeah, your realization is better.

Comment: arguments has always worked inside .apply calls, it is this way by design - you can use .apply on arguments for some time. There are a bunch of other issues with arguments but this is not one of them - not even going to mention the fact this is using ES6 promises, so browser support is probably not an issue :D

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum maybe should be written  `return result.done
            ? value
            : value.then(onValue, iter.throw.bind(iter));`, what do you think?

Comment: I'm not a fan of the ternary operator - I think it reduces readability. Then again it's your answer and feel free writing it any way you'd like.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Hmm... I don't know. You think now become worse?

Comment: I think it became worse - but this is subjective. The initial edit had two actual problems (deferred anti-pattern and error handling), the current version is fine - using if or using the ternary operator isn't a huge deal. Also - it's worth mentioning this version is still simplified and has issues with error handling (what if calling callback throws?) It's good enough for an answer though :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I returned your code. The answer is mine, but this code is yours after all. What about issues with error handling, I already wrote "simplest possible spawn realization can be something like".  I think this is enough.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Well, thanks for your remarks. This was very helpful.

Comment: Guys, reading this one with interest and trying to learn. Please help me - in the fourth code block, where does `value` come from?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I think today you deserve "bug seeker" badge, if was such)

Comment: Yeah, Benjamin knows, I can get under people's skin on occasions. Truth is, I only bother with answers that are worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks for the youTube link. How are non-native English speakers supposed to keep up with that guy - he speaks so fast?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Well, he can slow down the video speed  ("settings" in the right bottom corner, or just [Shift + '<']). Unfortunately I didn't find text version of presentation, and this video doesn't have subs.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 But if he's a programmer he must know english at least on the basics level and as I myself is non-native English speaker I think he can understand the guy. There is slides after all, which show everything he explains.

Comment: @alexpods, don't worry about me, English.is my mother tongue. I'm concerned for everyone else!

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I added remark about slowing the speed of playing down. Maybe it'll help to someone.

Comment: Unfortunately that play-speed control doesn't work in all browsers/players.

Comment: great answer and thanks for the tip about slowing it down, English is my mother tongue, but Jeez, it's early and I am trying to give up coffee.

Comment: Just a little note to the second code snippet, you can simplify it to this: `ourImportantFunction() { return Promise.resolve(task1()).then(task2).then(task3); }` unless `task1` already returns a Promise, then you can remove `Promise.resolve`.

Answer (score 11):

Promises and Generators are different software patterns (constructs):

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(computer_programming)

In fact, generators aren't asynchronous.

Generators are useful when you need to get a series of values not at once, but one per demand. Generator will return next value immediately (synchronously) on every call until it reaches the end of the sequence (or endless in case of infinite series).

Promises are useful when you need to "defer" the value, that may not be computed (or may not be available) yet. When the value is available - it's the whole value (not part of it) even it is an array or other complex value.

You can see more details and examples in wikipedia articles.