# readable async codeflow in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am new to async programming in node js and want to know how to translate my former (sync) programming to readable async programming in node js. Especially this example:

```
function getDefaultValue1() {
    return getDefaultValue1FromDB();
};
function getDefaultValue2() {
    return getDefaultValue2FromDB();
};

function doSomething(var optionalValue1, var optionalValue2){
    try {
        if(optionalValue1===null){
            optionalValue1 = getDefaultValue1();
        }
        if(optionalValue2===null){
            optionalValue2 = getDefaultValue2();
        }
        var resultList = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < optionalValue2; i++) {
            resultList.push(functionWithDbCall(optionalValue1, i));
        }
        return doSomeCalculations(resultList);
    }catch(var e){
        //log exception
        return null
    }
};
```

Note that all DB-Calls would be async in node js (getDefaultValue1FromDB(var callback), functionWithDbCall(var optionalValue1, var i, var callback)).

My thoughts are:
Adding callback-parameter to getDefaultValue => requires the same code in callback and after if. For loop exits before callbacks are called and callbacks need to handle how often they are called and to check to push the items in correct order. Changing a function to using an async method requires changing code everywhere it is called like changing getDefaultValue from returning a const int to a DB-call.

I am stuck here and all I found where advertising for some libraries or unreadable code worse then asm or regex (write once, read/touch never again). Did I miss something basic in my node js learning material or is this a design failure of the language?

So I hope somebody somebody can show me how to write this simple function readable with async node js.

Comment: Async code is not at all hard to read. You're only not used to it. I've been writing async code in Tcl since 1999 so when ajax came along I was like: hey, this is familiar! Same thing happened when node.js came along, I was like: hey, this is like coding in the browser! Code/design patterns you're not used to always appears hard/unreadable in the beginning. If you go to the PICLIST forums you'll find people who wouldn't touch C because for loops and if/else are confusing - they program exclusively in assembly.

Comment: The thing is, async code is fast. It's what makes javascript fast, it's fast in Python, it's even fast in C (my previous job was at Nokia maintaining database code written in C using asynchronous I/O in order to get the throughput telcos expect from phone directories). If you refuse to get used to async code you'll never leverage its advantage. On the other hand once you get it you can write async code in any language. Javascript only makes async code highly readable. Try doing it using a state machine implemented as a switch-case statement in a while loop in C and it's a lot more messy.

Comment: @slebetman I am used to async programming with pthreads et alii with multithreading and mutexes where you do it 1-10 times per program. In node js you do it 1-10 times per function. Code like if(x){A()};B(); becomes if(x){A(B)};B(); (repeating B) and things like ordered async in for loops are really screwing my mind. It totally inverts the codeflow and thinking and readability (you suddenly have 5 lines boilerplate code per for-loop. Even asm has straightforward codeflow. Good I used the XC866 which is commonly programmed in C and only the interrupt table in asm but only has 256 byte RAM ;)

Comment: Because I want to learn it right I asked the question how others do it instead of doing it wrong all the time.

Comment: Multithreaded programming and async programming are not the same. Async programming is almost 100% of the time single threaded (there are exceptions like node.js disk I/O). In college I learned both: threads and `select()`. That was in C of course - js wasn't on our collective radars back then.

Comment: Note also that asm codeflow is not always straightforward. If you program kernel device drivers then you must program asm asynchronously (queue this function pointer etc.. it's callbacks, just in asm)

Comment: @slebetman yes, that was about that what I ment with 1-10 times per program vs 1-10 times per function  (background jobs, tcp-connection-clients, adding jobs to an async queue, ...). 1% of the functions beeing async vs. 99% beeing async. Try catch blocks beeing practically useless. The asm call backs you describe are mostly called interrupts ;) and I know you can also write spaggethi code in asm or a goto-hell in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using Bluebird:

```js
var Promise = require('bluebird');

/**
 * Lets assume getDefaultValue1FromDB() passes a callback fn;
 * @return {Promise}
 */
function getDefaultValue1() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        return getDefaultValue1FromDB(function(err, value){
            if (err) return reject(err);
            return resolve(value);
        });
    });
}

/**
 * Lets assume getDefaultValue2FromDB() passes a callback fn;
 * @return {Promise}
 */
function getDefaultValue2() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        return getDefaultValue2FromDB(function(err, value){
            if (err) return reject(err);
            return resolve(value);
        });
    });
}

/**
 * @param  {Promise|int} optionalValue1
 * @param  {Prommise|int} optionalValue2
 * @return {Promise}
 */
function doSomething(optionalValue1, optionalValue2){

    if(optionalValue1 === null)
        optionalValue1 = getDefaultValue1;
    if(optionalValue2 === null)
        optionalValue2 = getDefaultValue2;

    return Promise
      .all([optionalValue1, optionalValue2])
      .spread(function(val1, val2){
          var resultList = [];
          for(var i = 0; i < val2; i++) {
              resultList.push(functionWithDbCall(val1, i));
          }
          return doSomeCalculationsAsync(resultList);
      }).catch(function(err){
          //Log any errors here.
      });

}

/**
 * Calls the db and returns a promise with the result.
 * @return {Promise}     [description]
 */
function functionWithDbCall(val, i) {
  Return new Promise();
}

/**
 * @param  {[Promise]} list Array of promises.
 * @return {Promise}
 */
function doSomeCalculationsAsync(list) {
    return Promise.all(list).then(doSomeCalculations);
}
```

Note that `doSomething` will return a promise, so you'll have to add a `.then()` to handle the results. Also asume that `functionWithDbCall` returns a Promise as well, you can then put all those together in a `Promise.all()` and then do the calculations.

Comment: bluebird was one of the libraries a came across - beside async.js. So readable code is only possible with external libraries? I think I didn't made it clear in the question that it would be functionWithDbCall(val1, i, callback) when async or do you mean to use the same pattern as in getDefaultValue1?

Comment: You could use native promises in node in es6, but don't know if they are the same. I edited the answer, you could wrap doSomeCalculations in doSomeCalculationsAsync, where you'll pass all the promises returned by functionWithDbCall, once you get all of them, continue with the calculation.

Comment: Do I have to consider about the Promises in your code as return values? Because you used them without .then() in the function. How do I access the value?

Comment: You can have an array of promises, i.e.: `[returnsAPromise(), Promise.resolve("foo"), 250, "foo"]`, in fact, a value such as `"foo"` will be considered a resolved promise, such as `Promise.resolve("foo")`. You can then pass that array to `Promise.all()` or `Promise.each()` and so forth. I recommend you read the Bluebird [docs](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [async/await](https://tc39.github.io/ecmascript-asyncawait/) from the ES7 proposal - a future version of JavaScript. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28032438/5574539) on how to **migrate from callbacks to promises to async/await.**

To actually run future code today, you will need to compile it down to currently supported features with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). Plus it can do [a lot more](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/) than async/await.

Comment: I hope the proposal is finalized soon and incorporated soon because my node_modules folder of a simple express app already has 30MB and takes a minute to start because of needing hundred modules for everything. Allthough the return statements look misleading for someone inexperienced in callback orientated languages like me it looks very clean. I will look at it closer later.